# Are there any tutorial/code samples on controlling an animation with a gesture on a tablet?

Tags: android, animation, gesture, expand, tablet

What I mean by controlling an animation with a gesture, is like that I have an animation where my view object folds into itself. I want it to fold into itself when I slide my finger right-to-left across the screen, and if I slide it the other way at any point it will start to unfold.

I basically want the animation to react with a gesture I am doing. Similar to flipboard, pageflip and a SlidingDrawer, except my animation is defined in XML.

Does anyone know if anything like this is possible. My apologies for not being able to explain any better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this I think you should find solution
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/07/flip-animation-in-android.html
http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/215-handling-finger-gestures